# Why does isTRUE improve this integer comparison

Tags: r

I just started with R and I've come across an issue I can fix but not quite understand.

**Consider this simple code:**

```
foo <- function(v) {

for(i in 1:length(v)-1)
  if(v[i] > v[i+1])
    #do something here

return()
}


v <- c(10, 40, 40, 10, 20, 70, 30, 20)

foo(v)
```

Running it will give this error:

```
Error in if (v[i] > v[i + 1]) return() : argument is of length zero
```

But replacing the if with the following code gets rid of the error:

```
if(isTRUE(v[i] > v[i+1]))
```

I come from a C/Java background so my question is, **why**? Why does this simple integer comparison need to be wrapped in isTRUE to work?
On similar questions I've found that isTRUE helps protect against cases where one of the two arguments is NA or NULL, but why is this the case here with two numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1:length(v)-1` is intepreted as `(1:length(v))-1`. In R arrays start at 1. You should instead have `1:(length(v)-1)`:

```
> length(v)
[1] 8
> 1:length(v)-1
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
> 1:(length(v)-1)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
> v[9]
[1] NA
```

Complete function:

```
foo <- function(v) {
  
  for(i in 1:(length(v)-1))
  {
    if(v[i] > v[i+1])
    {
      #do something here
    }
  }
  return()
}

v <- c(10, 40, 40, 10, 20, 70, 30, 20)
```

```
> foo(v)
# NULL
```

`isTRUE(x)` returns `TRUE` if, and only if, `x` is `TRUE`. This means that:

```
isTRUE(NA)
[1] FALSE
```

However:

```
> NA == TRUE
[1] NA
```

(not `FALSE`)

Comment: Really didn't think of this R feature with whole-array arithmetics, still pretty new to me, thank you very much!